# PDO: How to make checks

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I create this class but i'm newbie in PHP OOP & PDO and i don't know how and where i must to make check to username is valid , email is valid and e.t.c..

This is my code

```
Class Users {
    private $db;

        public function __construct(Database $datebase) {
            if (!$database instanceOf Database) {
                throw new Exeption();
            }
            $this->db = $datebase;
        }

        public function userRegistration($username, $password, $email) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $email    = $_POST['email'];
            $regdate  = date('d.m.Y');

                $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `regdate`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ");
                $query->bindValue(1, $username);
                $query->bindValue(2, $password);
                $query->bindValue(3, $email);
                $query->bindValue(4, $regdate);

            return ($query->execute()) ? true : false ;
        }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"? Also, why are you replacing your parameter values by a `$_POST` value?

Comment: Valid like "correct" . I mean for example "Username is to short. Min symbols 4" something like this.

Comment: What is your rule set for each field?

Comment: The code i've given is everything that i have and registration html form

Comment: You must know what is "valid" within your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check something, use [Respect/Validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation). For example:

```
$usernameValidator = v::alnum()->noWhitespace()->length(1,15);
$usernameValidator->validate($_POST['username']); //true or false

$passwordValidator = v::alnum()->length(10, null);
$passwordValidator->validate($_POST['password']); //true or false

v::email()->validate($_POST['email']); //true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if the username or email exist in your database you can use SQL to search the email or username.

```
  $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? ");
                $query->bindValue(1, $email);
```

If the query returns a value than the email or username already exist in your database. From there you can show your own validation.

Answer (score 0):

To check check if user or email exist you don't need another class, just add another method called userExist or emailExist and run a query and then check if you get a result.

```
  public function emailExist($email){
       $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? ");
       $query->bindValue(1, $email);
       try{
           $query->execute();
           //use the if statement and $query->rowCount() to check if there is a result
            $rows = $query->rowCount();
            if($rows === 1){
                  return true;
            } else {
                  return false;
            } 
       }catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
       }
  }
```

Comment: So do not make any verification. Query is sent even 2 times in to datebase.

`if ($users->userExists($_POST['username']) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'Exists';
   }`

There is also this error - `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: Yeah. No need for verification. Just makes sure that the new user does not use an email already in the database. You do the verification in another method